# Concat in an empty array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was browsing through some code and I was wondering how this could be useful

```
grid.push([].concat(row));
```

In my understanding it is the same as

```
grid.push([row]);
```

Why the 'concat' fuss?

Comment: Because `row` might be a primitive (or simply not an array) value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use `.concat` when you need to flatten the array and not have an array consisting of other arrays. E.g.

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4];
```

**Scenario 1**

```
console.log(b.push(a));
// Result: [4, [1,2,3]]
```

**Scenario 2**

```
console.log(b.concat(a));
// Result: [4,1,2,3]
```

So both of your scenarios in an array of array. Since `[].concat()` results in an array only, pushing both `[row]`, `[].concat(row)` has the same result.

But if you want a flattened array, there is a slight change needed in your code, that you have to `.concat` the array `row` with `grid` and not `.push` the result of concat to it, as shown in scenario 2

Comment: `console.log(b.push([a]));`... (`grid.push([row]);`). It is how OP has specified in post.. I am curious about the difference...

Comment: Both will produce array of an array...Better to provide executable snippet with valid syntax as provided in question...

Comment: By both do you mean `b.concat(a)` and `b.push(a)` or the ones referred in OPs question?

Comment: We are dealing with the code OP has provided right ? I am not concerned with the code provided in your answer..

Comment: Ok. On second glance I got what you were telling. Let me updated the answer

Answer (score 9):

Check my variant:

```
let arr = [];
let tmp = [ 1, 2, '300$' ];
arr.push(...tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var canEmptyArray = [];
grid = [...(grid), ...(canEmptyArray), ...(row)];
```

All arrays can be empty as long as it is in the array format

Answer (score 0):

With `grid.push([row]);` you are pushing an array containing the `row` itself. If row is an array (e.g. `[0, 1, 2]`). You will push an array containing another array (i.e. `[[0, 1, 2]]`).

With `grid.push([].concat(row));`, you are pushing an array containing the elements contained in `row` (i.e. `[0, 1, 2]`).

However it is unclear why it is not just written `grid.push(row)` which, if `row` is an array, could seem more or less the same as `grid.push([].concat(row));`.

I can find two explanations for this:

1. `row` is not an array but an "array-like" object and `[].concat(row)` is used to convert it (just like [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) could do).
2. Your coder does not want to push `row` but a copy of row instead that protected against any further modification of the original `row`.