# items = [].concat(items) what does it do?

Tags: javascript

what does `items = [].concat(this.items)` do? Looking at some JavaScript code explaining [Model-View-Controller (MVC) in JavaScript](https://alexatnet.com/model-view-controller-mvc-in-javascript/) but am confused as to the purpose of this `concat` statement. What does it achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concat in an empty array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477483/concat-in-an-empty-array-in-javascript)

Comment: You should probably edit this question to include the relevant function from the article. Makes it easier to see in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That clones the array and returns the **reference** to the new array.

So when you call `getItems` function and manipulating its return, that **won't affect** the original cloned array

for more refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23536726/4591364):

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's there to clone the array rather than returning a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Creates an empty array, and concatenates the values in the `this.items` array, it also creates its own copy so any changes you make to `items` will not be reflected in `this.items`